# wedge volume problem

Tags: calculus, volume, multiple-integral

> Find the volume of the wedge cut from the first octant by the cylinder
> $z = 12 - 3y^2$ and the plane $x+y=2$.

What I did- sketched parabola and repeated in all of x axis, drew the plane and found the domain in which its to be integrated which is
$0<y<2$ and $2-y<x<2$. The problem is it's wrong. It would be great if anyone could show the right direction to solve the problem

Comment: Is the plane $x+y=2$?

Comment: yes, completed the question

Comment: Let me guess, you're getting 12 but the answer wants 20.

Comment: Yes you are right @eyeballfrog

Comment: Then the problem wants the triangle that contains the origin (which has volume 20), not the other one. It perhaps could have been more clear about this.

Answer (score 1):

In Cartesian coordinates, one integral for the volume could be

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{2-x} \int_0^{12-3y^2} dz \, dy \, dx = \int_0^2 \int_0^{2-x} (12-3y^2)\, dy \, dx$$

or by swapping $x$ and $y$ (permissible by symmetry),

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{2-y} (12-3y^2) \, dx \, dy$$

Comment: Why did you choose the triangle closer to the origin and not the other one?

Comment: What other triangle? In the first octant, the plane $x+y=2$ splits the space into one bounded region (the one over which I take the integral) and an unbounded one.

Comment: As the q states, by cylinder and plane in first octant. Can't we take the triangle (0,2) (2,0) (2,2) as domain into consideration?

Comment: No, because the plane $x=2$ is not a part of the boundary. The solid is in the first octant, so by default $x\ge0$, $y\ge0$, and $z\ge0$. The only other boundaries for the solid are $x+y=2$ and $z=12-3y^2$.